# Transparent UIToolBar with Non-transparent UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a transparent UIToolbar by setting the translucent true and changing the background alpha. How can I make the toolbar button's not transparent? I tried adding a non transparent image like this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, ([AppDelegate isInIPad])?768:320, 20);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self.filterButton setBackgroundImage:image forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[yourToolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];    
[yourToolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];    
[yourToolbar setShadowImage:[UIImage new] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny];
```